# Common Lisp, remove element from list destructive

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a list with cons-pairs, *e.g.* `'((a . 3) (b . 2))`. I want to remove a cons-pair destructive if the first element in the cons-pair matches var. My function cannot remove the cons-pair if there is only one cons-pair in the list or if it is first in the list.

```
(defun delete-bindings! (var symbol-table)
(cond
 ((endp symbol-table) '())
 ((eql var (caar symbol-table))
  (delete-bindings! var (cdr symbol-table)))
 (t (setf (cdr symbol-table) (delete-bindings! var (cdr symbol-table)))
   symbol-table))))
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: In Common Lisp, destructiveness is typically an "efficiency hack". It's, in the general case, hard-to-impossible to destructively remove the first cons of a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is always returning `'()`, I think (can't be sure since you didn't show the whole thing).

Perhaps:

```
(defun delete-bindings! (var symbol-table)
  (cond
   ((endp symbol-table) '())
   ((eql var (caar symbol-table))
    (delete-bindings! var (cdr symbol-table)))
   (t (progn
        (setf (cdr symbol-table) (delete-bindings! var (cdr symbol-table)))
        symbol-table)))
```

Addendum:

You must use the result of this function, not simply depend on its side effects:

```
(setq *bindings* (delete-bindings! 'var *bindings*))
```

Second addendum

```
Loading ~/ccl-init.lisp
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.7-dev-r14406M-trunk  (DarwinX8632)!
? (defun delete-bindings! (var symbol-table)
  (cond
   ((endp symbol-table) '())
   ((eql var (caar symbol-table))
    (delete-bindings! var (cdr symbol-table)))
   (t (progn
        (setf (cdr symbol-table) (delete-bindings! var (cdr symbol-table)))
        symbol-table))))
DELETE-BINDINGS!
? (delete-bindings! 'a '((a . 3) (b . 2)))
((B . 2))
?
```

If you need a data structure that may be destructively modified with all references to it updated, you'll need another level of indirection.

E.g.,

```
(defvar *symbol-table* (cons 'bindings '((a . 3) (b . 2))))

(defun delete-bindings! (var symbol-table)
  (flet ((db! (var symbol-table) (cond
   ((endp symbol-table) '())
   ((eql var (caar symbol-table))
    (delete-bindings! var (cdr symbol-table)))
   (t (progn
        (setf (cdr symbol-table) (delete-bindings! var (cdr symbol-table)))
        symbol-table)))))
  (rplacd symbol-table (db! var (cdr symbol-table)))))
```

Comment: Yes I missed the last line of code when posting, now its complete. Thanks, but it does not work.

Comment: See my addendum; the function doesn't change the places that refer to the old value of the list (it can't since you pass the list of bindings by value, not by reference).

Comment: If I understood right what you mean then delete-bindings shouldn't work for symbol-table: '((a . 2) (b . 3)) and var: 'b. But it's possible to delete 'b but not 'a with my function.

Comment: Works for me; see second addendum

Comment: Yes it returns the correct list but if you set the symbol-table as a global variable (setq symbol-table '((a . 3) (b .2))) and sends it too delete-bindings! it doesn't change the list destructive. The global variable symbol-table doesn't change.

Comment: That's what I meant by "You must use the result of this function, not simply depend on it's side effects". The list is changed destructively, but the function doesn't modify the global binding which points to a cons cell that was removed from the list. That's why I suggested using: (setq *bindings* (delete-bindings! 'var *bindings*))

Comment: Okey I understand is there any other way to do it so I don't need to use setq on the result. Is it possible to modify the global binding to point to the new first cons cell in the list? Thanks!

Comment: See example of method to avoid needing to use setq on the result; you'll need to change all functions operating on the symbol table to use the new format.

Answer (score 1):

Functions cannot modify a variable that they get as argument, they always receive the variable's value instead of the variable itself. Instead, you can use [DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_2.htm):

```
(define-modify-macro delete-bindings! (item)
  (lambda (symbol-table item)
    (remove item symbol-table :key #'car)))
```

Comment: Isn't a destructive function, a function that modifies a variable that they get as an argument?

Comment: @claytontstanley variable is a tricky word.  A destructive function may destroy "what" they're given (the interpretation of "what" depends on the function), but rebinding one of their caller's variables is just something Lisp function can't do.  That's why they return their argument: for cases when rebinding is necessary.  For example in `delete`'s case, when the list head has to be removed, the "variable" has to change to a new list head.  In other cases, it would be enough to simply rebind of of the `cdr`s in the chain.

Comment: @claytontstanley: E.g. in a function that takes a list: a variable that holds a list actually holds a reference to the first cons cell of that list. A function called with that variable receives a copy of that reference. Now that function can modifiy all the cars and cdrs in the list – doing so would make it a destructive function –, but it cannot change the fact that that variable holds this reference to the first of the cons cells. To do that, a macro is needed.

Comment: @Rörd: Thanks for taking the time to explain this a bit better. I understand now. Question though; since the value of symbol-table is being overwritten, isn't it safe to use delete (instead of remove)? And I would assume that delete would be faster.

Comment: @claytontstanley: It would not be safe if some other variable holds – directly or indirectly – a reference to any of the cons cells in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but unless you're doing this for self-teaching purposes, it would be easier with [`delete`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm)

Something like (untested):

```
(defun delete-bindings! (var symbol-table)
    (delete var symbol-table :key #'car))
```

Comment: I am doing this for self-teaching but I have tried using the delete function but I get the same result, if the cons-pair is first or the only one it is not deleted. Thanks!

Comment: If you use the return value from the delete function, then this worked for me in all cases; including when the cons-pair is first and when it is the only one. [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node144.html)